# Is there a way to change the highlight colour in 16.10?

Tags: 16.10, appearance

I looked at other answers about changing the orange highlight colour, but they all seem to apply to earlier versions. Using dconf-editor and modifying gtk-color-scheme (either through terminal or GUI) doesn't appear to work in 16.10

So, is it still possible?

Comment: What is "gym-color-scheme"?

Comment: @DK Bose It was supposed to be gtk-color-scheme, but it got autocorrected

Comment: In that case, you may try changing `selected_bg_color:#f07746` to some other color in `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` and in `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css`.

Answer (score -1):

why don't you try terminator. in this terminal you can highlight text easily.

this is the web site where you find more information.
https://gnometerminator.blogspot.in/p/introduction.html

Comment: OP is asking about GUI, not terminal.